# Calculation problem

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, layers, error, syntaxerror

Trying to calculate terms and failing.I'm trying to figure out what's the problem? Indicates that all documents are on an external disk and not on the computer.

`if("area" <=1000, $perimeter/1000, 0)`

[image]

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: Is there a space between `$`  and `perimeter`? Shouldn't be. What does the preview show if you enter simply `"area"`? It is a polygon layer, right? Try replacing  `"area"` with `$area`.

Comment: I'm able to use your expression: if("area" <=1000, $perimeter/1000, 0). Check the column heading name. Is it "area" or "Area" or maybe "Area2"? And why do you want to divide your perimeter by 1000?